# AWS Linux and Mercurial auto add to environment

Tags: apache, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I have a development server on an EC2 instance. Mercurial is also installed.
The environment is using an Apache server working from /var/www/html.

As this is a development environment, I want each commit to the repository will also be copied to the Apache folder (so we can add changes and see them on the fly instead of both committing and then copying to environment.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK - got it,
Simply need to auto update on trigger - 
Edit a config file (i.e. /etc/mercurial/hgrc) and add an hook:

[hooks]
changegroup = hg update

Cheers!